# How Can I Get the Index of An Item in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, listbox

I am adding items to a `ListBox` like so:

```
myListBox.Items.addRange(myObjectArray);
```

and I also want to select some of the items I add by the following:

```
foreach(MyObject m in otherListOfMyObjects) 
{
    int index = myListBox.Items.IndexOf(m);
    myListBox.SelectedIndices.Add(index);
}
```

however `index` is always `-1`.

Is there a different way to get the index of an object in a `ListBox`?

Comment: So you are want to load a list with say 100 items and have say 20 items "selected"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should make sure that `MyObject` overrides `Equals()`, `GetHashCode()` and `ToString()` so that the `IndexOf()` method can find the object properly.

Technically, `ToString()` doesn't need to be overridden for equality testing, but it is useful for debugging.

Comment: thanks! I forgot to override equals and hashcode...shame on me.

Comment: Did it work?  Someone further down said that IndexOf checks the reference, which means that my solution wouldn't work.

Comment: The solution fixed it.  I just overrode equals and like magic it was fixed.

Comment: Okay - be aware that the recommendation is that you always implement GetHashCode and Equals together, in case the object is used in a hashmap.

Answer (score 7):

You can use some kind of a key for values in the listbox, like GUIDs.  Then you can easily use `myListBox.Items.FindByValue(value)` to find the right item.

Answer (score 0):

IndexOf checks the reference, so if the items in otherListOfMyObjects don't reference the same exact objects in memory as myListBox.Items, then IndexOf won't work.

What you could do is use linq.  Here's some pseudocode that looks like C#, may compile and may actually work:

```
var items =  from x in myListBox.Items where otherListOfMyObjects.Any(y => y == x /*SEE NOTE*/) select x;
foreach(item i in items)
  myListBox.SelectedItems.Add(i);
```

Obviously, that won't work as y==x will always return false (that's why your current method won't work).  You need to substitute y==x to perform an equality comparison that will determine equality as YOU define it for MyObject.  You can do this by adding an ID as Fallen suggested or by overriding a buttload of methods as Neil suggested (+s for both of them), or by just determining which properties of MyObject to check in order to identify them as exactly the same object.

Comment: But Linq is SO MUCH COOLER OMG LOL