# Delphi Prism: How to override GetHashCode and Equals method for IndexOf to work correctly?

Tags: delphi, delphi-prism, gethashcode

I am not sure if I am doing this right. I have a list of objects in the listbox and need to use IndexOf to get an object's index in the list.

```
if AlarmListBox.items.indexOf(alrm.Tagname) = -1 then
```

alrm is an object of TAlarm class.

Based on a StackOverflow C# question ([How Can I Get the Index of An Item in a ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408320/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-listbox)), I try to override GetHashCode and Equals method, but still it doesn't work right.

Overriden Method:

```
TAlarm = class(System.Object)
  TagName:string;
  private
  protected
  public
  method Equals(obj:System.Object):Boolean; override;
  method GetHashCode:Int32; Override;
end;

method TAlarm.Equals(obj: system.Object):Boolean;
begin
    result := TAlarm(obj).Tagname.Equals(self.Tagname);
end;

method TAlarm.GetHashCode:Int32;
begin
    result := self.GetHashCode;
end;
```

This is how I populate AlarmListBox:

```
AlmGrp:= new TAlarmGroup;
AlarmListBox.items.Add(AlmGrp);
```

Compiler compiles without any errors, but when I debug the program line by line it always returns -1 and these overridden methods are never called or fired.

Am I implementing these overrides correctly? If not, how should I override them?

Sample code or hints or clues will be appreciated. Thanks,

**UPDATE:** To David Heffernan and others who have commented or answered, I think the problem might be that I am passing in two different object as Rob's last comment states. I do populate Listbox (UI) with TAlarmGroup but pass in TAlarm into IndexOf, although they both are identical classes. This is probably my problem. What I am really trying to do is populate Listbox with TAlarmGroup objects and through listbox.indexof by passing in the string (Tagname) I search for the object location. That's how it is done on Delphi XE it works great. The code above is not the actual code. Once I clean up the confusion in my code, it will probably work without overriding the GetHashcode and Equals method.

**UPDATE:** I think, I have stumbled onto something here. On Delphi XE or below, ListBox (UI) provides a method called AddObject. It's parameters are a string and an object respectively. So, when I populated objects into listbox I also provided the string to go along with it. When I searched I passed in a string or the alarm group name. IndexOf searched on this string against the string it had for each object I provided and not against the object's field (TagName). In Delphi Prism, listbox doesn't have a similar method as AddObject method but only Add that only accepts object as a parameter.

Comment: indexOf should work out of the box. Does it not?

Comment: I wonder how TAlarm.GetHashCode performs. I guess it causes a stack overflow. If that doesn't happen, I assume it is never called. I do wonder why it was overwritten at all. @David: if TagName is the criterion for equality, the code shown should be fine (although a bit clumsy).

Comment: @ David, That's what I thought initially, but it always returned -1 even when an object was already added to the list. So, I figured there I needed to override these method after reading someone else's stackoverflow question.

Comment: @ Rudy, You are right. Actually, I just debugged them line by line and they are never called.

Comment: A quick test shows `Items.IndexOf` works here also. What happens if you don't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and just use `IndexOf`? (Also, as an aside: You can change your `Equals` code to simply `Result := TAlarm(obj).TagName.Equals(self.TagName);`. The assignment of `result := false;` and the `if..then` in the test can be eliminated.

Comment: @ Ken White, From what I understand, IndexOf should work out of the box as David stated. That's how I utilized the method in my code. When it didn't work no matter what I did, I started to look around for answer and I stumbled upon Stackoverflow question. So, I decided to see if it will help and it doesn't so far. In fact, IndexOf still works the same returning -1 all the time.

Comment: Can you show how you populate the `ListBox.Items`?

Comment: The name `AlarmListBox` suggests it's a ListBox UI control. Such controls hold *strings*, not `TAlarm` objects, although what you add to it is a `TAlarmGroup`, which is also *not* a `TAlarm`, so why are you bothering with `TAlarm` methods at all? You demonstrate searching for an item matching `alrm.name`, but your `TAlarm` class has no `name` member. Could the reason that you're not finding what you're looking for simply be that what you're looking for really isn't in the list?

Comment: Please clear up your question. Show us full code. Is it TAlarm or TAlarmGroup? What is the DisplayMember for your list box? Do you implement ToString? Why do you call IndexOf passing a string? You are meant to pass an object surely?

Comment: @rob WinForms ListBox holds objects. The DisplayMember property identifies a member to be used to obtain a display name. If not defined then ToString is used. Bit different from VCL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of doing what you want with the base `TAlarm` class you provided. I've also provided implementations of the overloaded `Equals` and `GetHashCode` that seem  to work. (Again, I'm not a Prism/.NET developer; just trying to help out here.)

```
// In AlarmClass.pas
type
  TAlarm = class(System.Object)
    TagName:string;
  private
  protected
  public
    constructor;
    method Equals(obj:System.Object): Boolean; override;
    method GetHashCode:Int32; Override;
    method ToString(): String; override;
end;

implementation

method TAlarm.GetHashCode: Int32;
begin
  if Self = nil then
    Result := inherited 
  else
    Result := Self.TagName.GetHashCode;
end;

constructor TAlarm;
begin
  inherited;
end;

method TAlarm.Equals(obj: System.Object): Boolean;
begin
  if  (obj = nil) or (GetType() <> obj.GetType()) then
    Exit(False);
  Result := TAlarm(obj).TagName.Equals(Self.TagName);
end;

method TAlarm.ToString(): String;
begin
  Result := Self.TagName;
end;

// In MainForm.pas
method MainForm.button1_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
var
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  Idx := ComboBox1.SelectedIndex;
  if Idx <> -1 then
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex := ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(ComboBox1.Items[Idx]);
end;

method MainForm.MainForm_Load(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
var
  i, j: Integer;
  Alarm: TAlarm;
  aList: Array[0..4] of Object;
  aFind: Array[0..1] of Object;
begin
  j := 0;
  for i := 0 to 4 do
  begin
    Alarm := new TAlarm;
    Alarm.TagName := String.Format('Alarm{0}', i);
    aList[i] := Alarm;
    // Place items 1 & 3 in another array of searchable items -
    // just for fun. Not suggesting implementing your app this way
    // by any means.
    if (i mod 2) > 0 then
    begin
      aFind[j] := Alarm;
      Inc(j);
    end;
  end;
  ListBox1.Items.AddRange(aList);
  ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(aFind);
end;
```

Here's how it looks with an item  selected in the `ComboBox` after clicking the `Button`:

[image: Screen capture of object found in ListBox]

Comment: You are just adding strings to a list box. Why bother with TAlarm? You don't need it here.

Comment: WinForms ListBox items are often objects rather than strings. I believe that is what digital is intending to do.

Comment: @ David, I need to add objects and then search the listbox by passing the name of the object into indexof. Let me try ken's code.

Comment: My point was that `Equals` does get called if you properly override and use it. It had nothing to do with adding objects to the `ListBox`; read the first sentence. It was intended to show that Rob was probably right in his comment that what was being added to the `ListBox` weren't the `Alarm` objects, and that that was probably the reason `Equals` wasn't being called. (Also, after reading the first sentence, please read the last one (below the image).) :) But, @David, please feel free to post your answer and I'll happily delete mine. :)

Comment: @Ken digital has explained what he wants to do and it agrees with my interpretation (for once).

Comment: For what it is worth, if you add objects to the list (which you need to do), you can't pass strings to `IndexOf`, as I read the WinForms documentation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Rewritten. Better now? :)

Comment: Yes. It still looks like you are passing an object to `IndexOf()`. I mean I think that's what you need to do, but of course @digital has a different expectation. I've hit the end of my knowledge here. I would just use a naive for list to iterate across the list box and test the names. But there must be a native .net/WinForms way to do it.

Comment: That was the point; I'm passing an Object, but finding it in the ListBox by *name*. (Your point before was that I couldn't pass strings to `IndexOf` because I'd added `Objects`, so I found it by passing in an `Object` instead and using the overridden `Equals` to compare by *name*.

Comment: @ Ken, thanks for your great example. I've come to a conclusion. I am having such a terrible time with listbox which is supposed to be very easy to use, because I am actually dealing with two different classes even though they are identical. I am loading objects of a TAlarmGroup class and searching for index passing objects of a TAlarm class. That is the main problem. I like your example. From the looks of it I may still need to implement the overrides.

Comment: @Ken Surely `ComboBox1.Items[Idx]` is TAlarm and not `string`. Or did I read that wrong? FWIW, you don't need to declare the alarm instances as `Object`, your arrays should be `TAlarm[]` or whatever the Prism equivalent is.

Comment: @David: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind for future reference. Re: `ComboBox.Items` and `TAlarm` - you seem to find fault with either way I implement things you specifically said needed to be done, so I'll just quit now while I'm ahead. The question was specifically how to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` so they'd work with `IndexOf`, and I answered that question. Next time there's a Prism question, please post your attempt at an answer instead, and I won't post one. :)

Comment: @digitalanalog: Hopefully at least some of this will be useful. If not, it was an interesting learning experience for me; as I said, I have Prism as part of RAD Studio, but haven't had any need to use it before this question. Thanks. :)

Comment: Prism questions hard for me since I don't have it. But I know a smattering of winforms. Your two attempts were string/string and object/object, but no object/string. I don't know enough about the semantics of Equals to be authorative.

Comment: @ David, I am impressed for someone not to have Prism and still answer a lot of prism questions. It shows how great of a programmer you are. Thanks, again.

Comment: @digital I guess I must have a brass neck!! The funny thing is the help I've given you this past week has been WinForms rather than pure Prism, but I never use WinForms either!